# How can I link another project's css file in a cshtml file? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to link in cshtml-file on css-file from another project in asp.net core application.
My solution contains two projects, this look something like this:

1. Project1 (ASP.NET Core MVC)

There is wwwroot/css/site.css inside Project1

2. Project2 (ASP.NET Core MVC)

In file _Layout.cshtml (Project2) I want to link css-file from Project1, something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" asp-append-version="true" />
```

But I can't simple to write in href attribute path to Project1/wwwroot/css/site.css file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the absolute path of wwwroot in Project1,and add the following code to project2:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine("xxx/xxx/xxx/wwwroot")),
                RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
            });

            app.UseRouting();
```

and then call the files from wwwroot in Project1 like:

```
href="~/StaticFiles/..."
```